# How do I test the ROS version in C++ code?

Tags: ros, rosversion, roscpp, best-practices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I maintain a package that needs to support both `cturtle` and `diamondback`, at least for a while. It includes `<roslib/Clock.h>`, which is deprecated in `diamondback`. That generates a compiler warning. I prefer to reserve compiler warnings for actual bugs in my code.

How can I `#ifdef` this code so it includes `<roslib/Clock.h>` in `cturtle`, but uses `<rosgraph_msgs/Clock.h>` for `diamondback`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9562/how-do-i-test-the-ros-version-in-c++-code?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2011-03-25

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the roscpp package roscpp/include/ros/common.h has the following defines:

```
#define ROS_VERSION_MAJOR 1
#define ROS_VERSION_MINOR 4
#define ROS_VERSION_PATCH 5
#define ROS_VERSION_COMBINED(major, minor, patch) (((major) << 20) | ((minor) << 10) | (patch))
#define ROS_VERSION ROS_VERSION_COMBINED(ROS_VERSION_MAJOR, ROS_VERSION_MINOR, ROS_VERSION_PATCH)

#define ROS_VERSION_GE(major1, minor1, patch1, major2, minor2, patch2) (ROS_VERSION_COMBINED(major1, minor1, patch1) >= ROS_VERSION_COMBINED(major2, minor2,\
 patch2))
#define ROS_VERSION_MINIMUM(major, minor, patch) ROS_VERSION_GE(ROS_VERSION_MAJOR, ROS_VERSION_MINOR, ROS_VERSION_PATCH, major, minor, patch)
```

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Keivan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25583/keivan/) on 2018-06-28**:
If you have installed ROS through standard way on Linux, `common.h` is located here: `/opt/ros/{ROS_DISTRO}/include/ros/common.h`

**Comment by [Olivier Michel](https://answers.ros.org/users/13651/olivier-michel/) on 2022-04-26**:
This include file doesn't seem to exist in ROS 2 distributions (e.g., I searched on rolling, galactic and foxy). What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To expand on tfoote's answer, here is an example:

```
#if ROS_VERSION_MINIMUM(1, 4, 5) // if current ros version is >= 1.4.5
        // Diamondback code
#else
        // CTurtle code
#endif
```

---

Originally posted by [baxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/86/baxelrod/) with karma: 794 on 2011-06-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7